# Нормализация баз данных в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Сам язык я знаю неплохо, но вот нормализация - темный лес. Можете в двух словах объяснить суть (или цель) первых 3х форм нормализации?

Comment: А Вы [Нормальная форма в Википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0#.D0.9F.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B2.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BC.D0.B0.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D1.84.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BC.D0.B0_.281NF.29) читали ? Короче не получается.

Comment: Краткость - сестра таланта. Пользуююсь этой фразой с момента поступления в универ)

Comment: Зачем же было жертвовать единственным очком репутации: оно бы Вам пригодилось, достаточно принять ответ, если Вы считаете его исчерпывающим.

Answer (score 13):

Суть нормализации в том, чтобы избавиться от избыточности данных, т. е. от повторения одних и тех же данных в нескольких строках. Например, если Вы создаёте БД телефонный справочник, то гораздо разумнее будет связать таблицу "Город" с таблицей "Телефоны" (связь один-ко-многим: одной записи в таблице "Город" соответствует несколько записей в таблице "Телефоны"), чем писать название города 100500 раз в каждой строке, таким образом в таблице "Телефоны" будет ссылка на какой-то конкретный город. К тому же, если название города поменялось, то придётся его менять столько раз сколько телефонов в городе имеется, а в случае связи всего 1 раз в таблице "Город". С помощью связей также можно сделать каскадное обновление (обновление в главной и подчинённых таблицах) или удаление (удаление в главной и подчинённых таблицах) данных.

Нормальные формы:
Первая НФ: каждое поле должно быть неделимым (атомарным). Это означает, что не должно быть таких полей, которые можно логически как-то разбить на несколько других полей. Например, поле ФИО содержит запись "Иванов Сергей Петрович", его можно разбить на 3 поля: фамилия, имя, отчество.

Вторая НФ: каждая запись таблицы должна однозначно определяться значением первичного ключа. Это значит, что не должно быть повторяющихся записей в таблице.

Третья НФ: в таблице не должно быть полей, значения которых зависят от значений неключевых полей. Например, в таблице "Товар" есть поля "Цена", "Количество", "Стоимость"; здесь поле "Стоимость" зависит от значений первых двух полей, поэтому его нужно удалить из таблицы: потом всегда можно будет сделать запрос с вычисляемым полем или добавить вычисляемое поле в набор данных.

Comment: Много текста, наверное он правильный. +

Answer (score 0):

**Нормализация** - это выполнение определенных требований для устранения дублирования данных в БД. Это нужно т.к. дублирование данных - потенциальная причина нарушения их целостности.

Существует 6 (или 8 - смотря как считать) нормальных форм (НФ). Но обычно требуется приведение БД к первым 3-м.

| НФ | Требование | Примечание |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Отсутствие полей со множественными значениями | Т.е. поля "Friends" предполагающего значение "Nick, Mike, Alex" быть не должно |
| 2 | Отсутствие зависимости неключевых полей от части составного ключа | Наличие id автоматически приводит таблицу к соответствию этому требованию |
| 3 | Отсутствие зависимости неключевых полей от других неключевых полей | - |

Кроме описанных требований есть общее требование для всех НФ - соответствие предыдущей НФ (т.е. 3-я НФ предполагает обязательное соответствие 2-й НФ).

PS Вообще поля правильнее называть атрибутами, записи - кортежами, а таблицы - это не таблицы, а relation (отношения). Каноничные определения требований НФ в правильной терминологии найдете в Википедии. А тут я попытался объяснить суть, коротко и простыми словами.